# Bootstrap Popover - JS Trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to trigger Bootstrap's Pop Over with JS.

I want to be able to change the message and title relative to the link I click.

It works if I actually click the link, but I want to achieve this via Jquery .Click event.

Here is my current JS code:
//Global Tooltip Functionality

```
$(function () {
    $(".tool-tip").on("click",function () {
        //Initializes Tooltip
        $(function () {
            $("#ToolTipContainer").popover();
        });
        var title = $(this).attr("data-tooltip-title"),
            message = $(this).attr("data-tooltip-message");
        $("#ToolTipContainer").attr("title", title);
        $("#ToolTipContainer").attr("data-content", message);
        $("#ToolTipContainer").click();
    });
});
```

Here is my DOM element I am calling function from:

```
<button type="button" class="tool-tip btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" data-tooltip-title="Item Added" data-tooltip-message="Some Message">Continue Shopping</button>
```

Here is the pop-up container(css hides this, I only want to see the pop-up):

```
<a href="#" id="ToolTipContainer" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" data-placement="bottom" title="" data-content=""></a>
```

Bootstrap Documentation: [Bootstrap PopOver](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers)

Comment: Is there a reason why `$("#ToolTipContainer").popover('show')` won't work? (Which, btw, is explained in your linked docs page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can show a tooltip programatically by calling

.popover('show')

```
$(function () {
    $(".tool-tip").on("click",function () {
        //Initializes Tooltip
        $(function () {
            $("#ToolTipContainer").popover();
        });
        var title = $(this).attr("data-tooltip-title"),
            message = $(this).attr("data-tooltip-message");
        $("#ToolTipContainer").attr("title", title);
        $("#ToolTipContainer").attr("data-content", message);
        $("#ToolTipContainer").popover('show');
    });
});
```

Try not hiding the popover container as well, it is most likely hiding your popover.

Comment: Any idea how to set it to hide automatically?

Comment: @Mark: Its the same process you just pass 'hide' instead of 'show'. at the end of your click handler you could add a setTimeout(function(){ $('#ToolTipContainer').popover('hide'); }, 10000);  To hide it 10 second after it shows for example.